# mysql insert new records using a loop

Tags: mysql

I need to set up some initial records in our mysql database.

I insert a new record which gives me the siteID of the last insert I then use this in creating the rows in my allNews_copy table. The following works (syntax is from applicationcraft ide) as I get the correct structure but there is a 60 timeout for the call to the server.
Therefore the script stops after about 270 rows.

```
for(i3=1; i3<51; i3++) {
    //console.log('i3 =  '+i3 );
    for(i2=1; i2<101; i2++) {
        //console.log('i2 =  '+i2 );
        var isVisible2 = 0;
        if(i2 < 6){ isVisible2 = 1;}
        cObj.insert('allNews_copy',{
            siteID:siteID,
            newsIDInt:i2,
            catIDInt:i3,
            title:'Item title '+i2 + ' in Cat' + i3,
            newsDesc:'Item Desc',
            visible:isVisible2

        });
    }
}
```

The total number of rows would be 5000.
So can I do this by using a mysql loop via a std mysql syntax?

Comment: I am not sure. It is how they(applicationcraft.com) handle sever side scripts.

Comment: Running Javascript on the server is usually Node.js, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL syntax you can insert multiple rows in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (<list of columns>)
VALUES (<list of values>), (<list of values>), (<list of values>), ...
```

I don't know how to translate this syntax to the API you're using, though.